# Using PhP to control what is Printing

Tags: php, html

Good day everyone

I have a printing problem so I'm going to explain the problem and share some basic code but the coding is not the problem, the problem is that I'm using the wrong method there must be a better method.

My web page is generated by using PhP to fetch information from mySQL and display each set of information as a table. so I may have 3 tables on 1 page or 100 tables. the problem is I really need to print this but when I do google puts the page breaks straight through my table.

the tables vary in height depending on how much information I need to display.
I use javascript to set the print area.

below you will see I try anticipate the page break with table 3 but when table 1 and 2 take more than a page, it puts the break through table 2 then the rest of page 2 is empty and table 3 is only found on page 3. In this case i would need it to put the break before table 2 so the whole table prints on page 2.

```
<div id='print_area'>
  <table>
    this is table 1
  </table>

  <table>
    this is table 2
  </table>

  <table style='page-break-before:always'>
    this is table 3
  </table>

</div>
```

Sorry I need to leave for the day but I'm really hoping some one will be able to help with this problem. I will be checking back tomorrow.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You may as well always break page on each table so they appear on new pages every time, secondly, apply that page break CSS before the table itself, not on it. Lastly, there's some extra page break rules, depending on the browser.

Comment: Thank you for the page break location suggestion. is there not a way to apply page break after X-pixel or if during table then apply before table. the problem is my tables are 80% of the time only a quarter page.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you want is `page-break-inside: avoid`. However AFAIK browser support is not very good. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of rows in each table before you actually print them. Assume a number of rows that fit on a page, and space you need for table headers/space between tables.

So for example

```
$rows_between_tables=3
$rows_needed_for_header=2
$rows_used_on_this_page=0
$rows_per_page=72  # (depends on font size etc.)

while (there_is_another_table_to_print()) {
    $rows_after_this_table = $rows_used_on_this_page +
        $rows_needed_for_header + $rows_between_tables +
        rows_for_next_table()
    if ($rows_after_this_table > $rows_per_page) {
        $rows_used_on_this_page=$rows_needed_for_header + rows_for_next_table()
        print_next_table_with_page_break_in_front_of_it();
    }
    else {
        $rows_used_on_this_page=$rows_after_this_table;
        print_next_table_no_page_break();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll never really be able to guarantee page layout just using PHP and HTML. Have you considered creating a PDF instead of a printable web page? There are very simple but powerful PDF libraries available for PHP, my preferred one is [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/).

Comment: I'd go with this as well, although you never know about memory issues with pages 100+